# Thunderbolt-Firewire adapter: latency

Tags: audio-interfaces, firewire

I'm interested in using an old Firewire multichannel audio interface with a very recent Macbook that does not have Firewire but does have Thunderbolt.

Apple sells a $30 Firewire-Thunderbolt adapter.  Will this adapter be usable in the configuration I describe, and will the adapter add latency?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like a crapshoot from the reviews.  Some people had major issues, particularly with firewire powered devices, others had great luck.  Sounds like the best bet may be to get the cable and try it.  If there are problems, return it.